# Randomized complete block design

Tags: r, random, data-science

I am trying to do a "randomized complete block design" with 3 re-arrangements in R.
I am doing a pot experiment with 9 treatments (3 fertilizer and 3 pesticide treatments are combined) and 6 replicates each, therefore I have chosen 6 blocks. Within the block a treatment is allowed to occur once per arrangement and each individual pot is only allowed to occur once within a block over all arrangements.
For example: `C_p+Min_1` can be in block 1 the first time, but afterwards can not return in block 1 again. At the same time no other replicate of this treatment (`C_p+Min_2` - `C_p+Min_6`) can be in the same block as `C_p+Min_1`.
My block design is a 6 x 9 raster, where a block is 3x3 raster in a square:

[image: picture of 3x3 x 2 x 3 experimental design]

What I did:

```
library(agricolae)
pesticide <- factor(rep(c("C_p", "Bio", "Syn"), each = 3))
fertilizer <- factor(rep(c("C_f", "Org", "Min"), times = 3))

treatments <- data.frame(fertilizer, pesticide)
treatments_combined <- paste(treatments$fertilizer, "+", treatments$pesticide)

design.rcbd(trt=treatments_combined, r=6, randomization = TRUE, first=TRUE)$sketch
```

This results in:

```
      [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]       
[1,] "Org + C_p" "Org + Syn" "C_f + Syn" "Min + Syn" "C_f + Bio" "Min + C_p" "Org + Bio" "Min + Bio" "C_f + C_p"
[2,] "Min + Bio" "Min + Syn" "Min + C_p" "C_f + Bio" "Org + Syn" "C_f + C_p" "Org + C_p" "C_f + Syn" "Org + Bio"
[3,] "Org + Syn" "C_f + Bio" "C_f + Syn" "Org + Bio" "Org + C_p" "Min + C_p" "C_f + C_p" "Min + Syn" "Min + Bio"
[4,] "C_f + Bio" "Min + Bio" "Org + C_p" "C_f + C_p" "C_f + Syn" "Min + Syn" "Min + C_p" "Org + Bio" "Org + Syn"
[5,] "Org + C_p" "Org + Bio" "C_f + C_p" "C_f + Syn" "C_f + Bio" "Min + Bio" "Min + C_p" "Min + Syn" "Org + Syn"
[6,] "C_f + Syn" "C_f + C_p" "Min + Bio" "Org + Syn" "Org + Bio" "Min + C_p" "Org + C_p" "C_f + Bio" "Min + Syn"
```

So I get what I wanted once.
Now I want to rearrange them 3 times. How can I do that, so that my specifications from above are met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you simply re-run the `design.rcbd()` function you will get a new randomization. (The function has a `seed` argument if for some reason you want to fix the randomization to get the same result repeatedly.)

```r
set.seed(101)  ## for replicability in the future
designs <- replicate(4, simplify=FALSE,
     design.rcbd(trt=treatments_combined, r=6, 
                 randomization = TRUE, first=TRUE)$sketch)
```

This will give you a list of four "sketches" which you can retrieve as `designs[[1]]`, `designs[[2]]`, etc.

Alternatively you could save the entire design by leaving out `$sketch`:

```r
designs <- replicate(4, simplify=FALSE,
     design.rcbd(trt=treatments_combined, r=6, 
                 randomization = TRUE, first=TRUE))
```

Now use `designs[[1]]$sketch` to get the the design sketch for design 1 and `designs[[1]]$book` to get the "fieldbook", which I think is what you want for the detailed information on individual pots ...

```
  plots block treatments_combined
1    101     1           C_f + C_p
2    102     1           Org + C_p
3    103     1           Min + C_p
...
```

One way to extract information on a particular treatment combination:

```r
b <- designs[[1]]$book
dplyr::filter(b, treatments_combined == "Min + C_p")
  plots block treatments_combined
1   103     1           Min + C_p
2   207     2           Min + C_p
3   303     3           Min + C_p
4   404     4           Min + C_p
5   503     5           Min + C_p
6   608     6           Min + C_p
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer.
This looks great. Is there a way to enumerate all the pots? I need to be able to tell them apart, as I will be phyisically moving the pots to their new position after a certain time. 
For each treatment e.g. "C_p+Min" there are 6 replicates. So from C_p+Min_1 to C_p+Min_6 and I need to know which goes where. 
Thanks!